# Subtracting Variables with Autohotkey

Tags: math, autohotkey

I am building a macro in Autohotkey which requires me to subtract a number from a variable, as shown below:

```
screenWidth = 1280
MsgBox, screenWidth - 150
```

For some reason, whenever the dialog box appears with the message, all I get is `screenWidth - 150`, instead of `1130`. I get one step closer with this approach:

```
screenWidth = 1280
MsgBox, %screenWidth% - 150
```

For the above code, I get `1280 - 150`, but still no the mathematical result.

According to the documentation, code as simple as `Price * (1 - Discount/100)` should work, assuming that "Price" and "Discount" are both defined.

Could someone direct me as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My mistake, in the documentation of the `MsgBox` method, I am told that adding a percent sign to the end of `MsgBox` causes it to see the input as an expression. So `MsgBox % screenWidth  - 150` is now computed correctly.